# How to remove folder with npm before build

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, webpack, package.json

I've got a scripts 
`"build": "rimraf dist webpack --progress --config webpack/prod.js",`
But actually,it removed not dist but all file inside webpack folder. But I need delete only dist

```
Structure:
 -dist
 -webpack
     -somefiles.js
```

Comment: you can try this `rimraf dist; webpack --progress --config webpack/prod.js`

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Npm scripts are basically the same as running the commands directly in bash.
In your case, you are running `rimraf dist webpack` which means webpack is an argument for rimraf.
To separate commands, you can use `;` or `&` if you want to make sure the first command ran successfully before running the second one use `&&`
So your script should look like this.

`rimraf dist && webpack --progress --config webpack/prod.js`

Answer (score 7):

### Quick and easy cross platform solution. No need of any library

[+] Updated from the comments - *Handles error and prints to console*

In `package.json` adding a script that employs [node.js api](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_rmdir_path_options) to execute via inline execution

add below code in `package.json` script

```
{
  ...
  "scripts": {
     "rmdir": "node -e \"var fs = require('fs');process.argv.slice(1).map((fpath)=>{ try {fs.rmdirSync(fpath,{recursive: true})} catch(e){console.warn('Error folder:', fpath, e)}});process.exit(0);\"",
  }

}
```

**Then execute as below in command window**

```
npm run rmdir -- folder1 folder2
```

Comment: The script will give a runtime error in case the path provided is not valid ( example case: if the directory is not present ). To overcome this the updated script is  "rmdir": "node -e \"var fs = require('fs'); try{process.argv.slice(1).map((fpath) => fs.rmdirSync(fpath, { recursive: true }))}catch(err){console.log(`Dist not found`)}; process.exit(0);\""

Answer (score 2):

You can clean your output directory before emit by adding one line in your `webpack.config.js` file

```
clean: true,
```

Take a look at webpack output management : https://webpack.js.org/guides/output-management/#cleaning-up-the-dist-folder

i usually use `clean: argv.mode === "production"`

Answer (score 2):

```
 "rmdir": "node -e \"var fs = require('fs'); try{process.argv.slice(1).map((fpath) => fs.rmdirSync(fpath, { recursive: true }))}catch(err){console.log(`Dist not found`)}; process.exit(0);\""
```

The previous versions don't work if the directory isn't present. But this will to run it with a typescript configuration use

```
"scripts": {
"rmdir": "node -e \"var fs = require('fs'); try{process.argv.slice(1).map((fpath) => fs.rmdirSync(fpath, { recursive: true }))}catch(err){console.log(`Dist not found`)}; process.exit(0);\"",
"build":"npm run rmdir dist && tsc"
```

Then use npm run build to compile the TSX

Answer (score 1):

npm install --save-dev del-cli

"scripts": {
    "prebuild": "del-cli --force ../folder-to-delete"
}
notice "--force" when you want to delete a parent folder